# write immutable code for storing data in listBuffer in scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, immutability, lagom

I have the below code where I am using a mutable list buffer to store files recieved from kafka consumer , and then when the list size reached 15 I insert them into cassandra .
But Is their any way to do the same thing using immutable list.

```
  val filesList = ListBuffer[SystemTextFile]()
  storeservSparkService.configFilesTopicInBatch.subscribe.atLeastOnce(Flow[SystemTextFile].mapAsync(4) { file: SystemTextFile =>
    filesList += file
    if (filesList.size == 15) {
      storeServSystemRepository.config.insertFileInBatch(filesList.toList)
      filesList.clear()
    }
    Future(Done)
  })
```

Comment: What does `storeServSystemRepository.config.insertFileInBatch` do? Is that a synchronous operation or asynchronous? What is the method signature?

Comment: this inserts the data in batched of 15 , so here we are using the Lagom cassandra session and batch statement to insert data . Yes it return Future(done).

Comment: If `insertFileInBatch` returns `Future[Done]` then you should be returning that future from the block passed to `mapAsync`, rather than creating a new, independent future.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines?

```
Flow[SystemTextFile].grouped(15).mapAsync(4){ files =>
  storeServSystemRepository.config.insertFileInBatch(files)
}
```

Comment: when I add the grouped keyword then it does not consumes the messges.

Comment: Also If I tried with groupedWithin(15, Duration(20, "seconds")), then it only consumes 1 files in 20 sec while without the group keyword it consumes all the files (70) in milli seconds

Comment: According to @Piyush_Rana's comment above, `insertFileInBatch` returns a `Future[Done]`, so that should be returned directly rather than wrapping another `Future` around it. Would you like to update your answer or should I write a new one?

Comment: @Piyush_Rana does this updated version work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Vector?

```
      val filesList = Vector[SystemTextFile]()
      storeservSparkService.configFilesTopicInBatch.subscribe.
          atLeastOnce(Flow[SystemTextFile].mapAsync(4) { file: SystemTextFile =>
       filesList = filesList :+ file
       if (filesList.length == 15) {
            storeServSystemRepository.config.insertFileInBatch(filesList.toList)
       }
       Future(Done)
     })
```